# How to disable opening new Documentation Window when selecting an item from the Documentation Home page?

Tags: documentation

When I open the Wolfram Documentation Center, a new window opens to the Home page. If I select an item from the top category drop down (eg, Core Language & Structure -> Lists), a 2nd Documentation window will open to the Lists documentation page. Is it possible to disable opening the 2nd window and simply open the List page in the original documentation window? I've searched the Preferences for such a setting, but can't find anything. Sometimes I like to start browsing documentation from the Home page without having a specific function name in mind.

I'm running Win 10 Home, MMA v 11.

Here's a screen capture of what happens:

[image]

After selecting Core Language & Structure -> Lists:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've talked with WRI support about this. His response was that this behavior was introduced in version 10. He didn't have immediate knowledge as to why it was introduced. He noted that it did seem that one would expect to be able to open help items from the Home page in the same window. He also agreed that there is some inconsistent behavior in the current implementation. Some of the categories will open in the same window (eg. "Recent Features", "New Features", "Index of Functions"). I've also noticed that the behavior will be different (ie, toggle between pre-V10 and post-V10 behavior) on different computers or when running sessions at different times. The support engineer said he would mention this to the development team for further review. As of this time, there is no option setting to control the behavior. If anyone else would prefer to have this under user control, then you should contact WRI support to show that there is user demand.